# How do I integrate a given stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

The given stochastic process $X(t)$ with dynamics is,

$$ dX(t) = -aX(t)dt +\sigma dW(t) $$
$$ X(0)=0 $$

I want to integrate this. The answer to this is given in my text as,

$$ X(t) = \sigma \int_0^t e^{-a(t-u)} dW(u) $$

How does this happen?
When I applied Ito's Lemma on the $dX(t)$ equation, I ended up with

$$ X(t) = X(0)+\sigma \int_0^t dW(u) + (1/2) \int_0^t dt $$

which is absolutely wrong.

What mistake am I doing while applying the lemma? Where does the exponent come from?
I cannot figure out how to integrate a given stochastic process, and I'd genuinely appreciate any help!

**Important Edit**
After posting this, I tried using integrating factors to solve for $X(t)$ such that the equation becomes,

$$ e^{at}dX(t)= e^{at}(-aXdt + \sigma dW_t)$$
and on integrating, I get $$ X(t)= e^{-at}\int_0^t-e^{au}aXdu + e^{-at}\int_0^te^{au}\sigma dW_u $$

which is still not the required answer.
Can you please help me figure out why the deterministic part of the RHS becomes zero?

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake with your integrating factor.  Try applying Ito's lemma to $e^{at}X_t$, i.e. compute $d(e^{at}X_t)$.

Comment: @user6247850 I computed $$d(e^{at}X_t)$$ to get $$X(t) =X(0) + e^{-at} \int_0^t -e^{au}aXdu + e^{-at} \int_0^t e^{au} \sigma dW_u $$ which eventually becomes $$ X(t) = X[e^{-at}-1] +\sigma \int_0^t e^{-a(t-u)}dW_u $$ 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will apply Ito's formula to the process $e^{at}X_t$.  Let $f(t,x) := e^{at}x$, so by Ito's formula \begin{align*}
d(e^{at}X(t)) = df(t,X(t)) &= \partial_t f(t,X_t)dt + \partial_x f(t,X_t)dX(t) + \frac 12 \partial_{xx}f(t,X_t)dX(t)dX(t) \\
&= ae^{at}X(t)dt + e^{at}(-aX(t)dt + \sigma dW(t)) \\
&= \sigma e^{at}dW(t).
\end{align*}
Re-writing in integral form, this says
$$e^{at}X(t) = \int_0^t \sigma e^{as}dW(s) $$
so solving for $X(t)$ gives $$X(t) = e^{-at}\int_0^t\sigma e^{as}dW(s) = \sigma \int_0^t e^{-a(t-s)}dW(s).$$